# Is it possible to avoid caching when calling the extension method GetOrCreateAsync on an IMemoryCache?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, memorycache

I'm using an `IMemoryCache` to cache a token retrieved from an Identity server.

In the past I've used the [`GetOrCreateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync) extension method available in the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/) library.
It is very helpful because I can define the function and the expiration date at the same time.

However with a token, I won't know the **expires in** x amount of seconds value until the request is finished.
I want to account for a use case of the value not existing by not caching the token at all.

I have tried the following

```
var token = await this.memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync<string>("SomeKey", async cacheEntry =>
{
    var jwt = await GetTokenFromServer();
    var tokenHasValidExpireValue = int.TryParse(jwt.ExpiresIn, out int tokenExpirationSeconds);
    
    if (tokenHasValidExpireValue)
    {
        cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenExpirationSeconds);
    }
    else // Do not cache value.  Just return it.
    {
        cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0); //Exception thrown.  Value needs to be positive.
    }

    return jwt.token;
}
```

As you can see, an exception is thrown when I try to set an expiration of no time `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)`.

Is there a way around this besides calling the `Get` and `Set` methods separately?
I would like to use the [`GetOrCreateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync) method if possible.

Comment: What are you gaining from using `GetOrCreateAsync` other than confusing behavior?  If you do not consistently create an entry, calling `GetOrCreateAsync` makes zero sense.

Comment: @DavidL it simplifies my code

Comment: But *it clearly doesn't*.  As you've demonstrated, you have different expectations based on the data, which means that the method doesn't fit your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't actually accomplish this with the current [extension](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L109) because it will always create an entry **BEFORE** calling the factory method. That said, you can encapsulate the behavior in your own extension in a manner which feels very similar to `GetOrCreateAsync`.

```
public static class CustomMemoryCacheExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TItem> GetOrCreateIfValidTimestampAsync<TItem>(
        this IMemoryCache cache, object key, Func<Task<(int, TItem)>> factory)
    {
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out object result))
        {
            (int tokenExpirationSeconds, TItem factoryResult) = 
                await factory().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (tokenExpirationSeconds <= 0)
            {
                // if the factory method did not return a positive timestamp,
                // return the data without caching.
                return factoryResult;
            }

            // since we have a valid timestamp:
            // 1. create a cache entry
            // 2. Set the result
            // 3. Set the timestamp
            using ICacheEntry entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);

            entry.Value = result;
            entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenExpirationSeconds);
        }

        return (TItem)result;
    }
}
```

You can then call your extension method in a very similar manner:

```
var memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
var token = await memoryCache.GetOrCreateIfValidTimestampAsync<string>("SomeKey", async () =>
{
    var jwt = await GetTokenFromServer();
    var tokenHasValidExpireValue = int.TryParse(jwt.ExpiresIn, out int tokenExpirationSeconds);

    return (tokenExpirationSeconds, jwt.token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the need for this and simply set the expiration time to now, I assume you can set it to past time as well just to be sure:

```
// Don't wanna cache if this is the result
if (key == null || key.Expiration < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    entry.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something in these lines:

```
await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync("key",
  async entry =>
  {
      var value = // get your value here;

      entry.AbsoluteExpiration = value != null
          ? DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
          : DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;              // don't cache nulls

      return value;
  });
```